# WP Function Add Body Class Based on Subcategory Count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

On an category archive page, I'm displaying the products with the subcategories in the sidebar. The visitor can then drill down using the subcategories or select a product. When there are no more subcategories, I'd like to add a body class that would trigger the CSS with that body class.

Currently, the class `'no-more-subcategories'` is being added, even when there are subcategories present.

```
function noMoreSubCategories ($classes) {
    if (count( get_term_children( $term_id, 'product_cat' )) == 0) {
        $classes[] = 'no-more-sub-categories';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'more-sub-categories';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','noMoreSubCategories' );
```

Comment: You don't say if there's a problem at all, just what your goal is. However, you are using a single `=` which is not equality, it is assignment and should be throwing a warning or error depending on your PHP version. Try changing it to `===`

Comment: Thank you! I replaced = and wrapped the count in ( ) which is now passing the php validation though it's still giving me some challenges. I do appreciate your help getting past that hurdle :)

Comment: Where do you imagine `$term_id` to come from inside that function?

Comment: Thank you! These little hints help me learn better then just the answer, you pointed my in the right direction and I got it working. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Adds a class to the body based on if sub-categories are available.

```
function noMoreSubCategories ($classes) {
    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    if (count( get_term_children( $term_id, 'product_cat' )) == 0) {
        $classes[] = 'no-more-sub-categories';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'more-sub-categories';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','noMoreSubCategories' );
```